# SVG manipulate gradiant fill color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, angularjs-directive

I want to programly manipulate gradient fill color in a simple svg rectangle.

There are 2 solutions. I don't like drawing multiple rects and concat them together to get a big one. So I am trying this gradient color approach.

> What I did was trying to insert "stop" tags in the "linearGradiant" tag, before SVG start
>   drawing rectangle. But somehow my code is not working.
>
> I could see the rectangle was drawn after I run my code but the
>   rectangle just was not rendered. If I change fill from "url(#c1)" to "blue", I could see the rect will be rendered blue.

Code is using AngularJS directive.

```
'use strict'

angular.module('StanfordClinicalGenomics').directive('chromosomeFillChart', ['$compile', '$location',function($compile,$location) {

return {

    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "app/directives/chromosome_fill/chromosome_fill.html",
    scope: {
        data: "=data",
        cid: "=cid",
        vid: "=vid",
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile, $http, $route, $rootScope, $timeout) {

        var data = $scope.data;

        if ($scope.cid){
            var chart = d3.select('chromosome-fill-chart[cid='+"'"+$scope.cid+"'"+'] svg.withFill') //this is just a selector
            .attr("width", 30)
            .attr("height", 100);


            $timeout(function(){
                angular.element("#c"+$scope.cid).append($compile('<stop offset="33%" stop-color="skyblue" />')($scope));

                angular.element("#c"+$scope.cid).append($compile('<stop offset="33%" stop-color="#FF6" />')($scope));
                $scope.$apply();
                var bar = chart.append("g")
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 30)
                .attr("fill", "url(#c"+$scope.cid+")")
                .attr("height",data[0]);


            });       
        }
    }
}
```

}]);

Below is the html:

```
<svg class="withFill">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="c{{cid}}" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"></linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Below is code in my Chrome browser:

```
<chromosome-fill-chart data="[100,20,76]" cid="1" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<svg class="withFill" width="30" height="100">

    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="c1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="33%" stop-color="skyblue" class="ng-scope"></stop>
          <stop offset="33%" stop-color="#FF6" class="ng-scope"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>


<g><rect width="30" fill="url(#c1)" height="100"></rect></g>
</svg>
</chromosome-fill-chart>
```

Comment: Just in case, my desired effect would be a rectangle filled with 2 different color. Top to 33% would be skyblue and 33% to 100% would be yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append your `<stop>` elements with d3, not angular.  I'm pretty sure that Angular's `$compile()` will be creating `stop` elements that are in the HTML/default namespace.  However they need to be in the SVG namespace.